# STM32: Timer encoder reset

Tags: stm32, timer, interrupts, encoder, rotary

I configured my TIM4 as encoder input and everything is working well when I execute TIM_GetCounter(TIM4)
But I would like to put the timer value back to 0 (reset?) when I press a push button with an interrupt on it) and I don't find a reset function. I'm running a STM32F103 with only StdPeriph Lib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write one for yourself based on the 'get' function:

```
uint32_t TIM_GetCounter(TIM_TypeDef* TIMx)
{
  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_TIM_ALL_PERIPH(TIMx));

  /* Get the Counter Register value */
  return TIMx->CNT;
}
```

So a `TIM_ResetCounter` should look like this:

```
void TIM_ResetCounter(TIM_TypeDef* TIMx)
{
  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_TIM_ALL_PERIPH(TIMx));

  /* Reset the Counter Register value */
  TIMx->CNT = 0;
}
```

If you check in the [reference manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf), you can see that the counter value register has read-write access. So you can set it to 0.

[image]

You can create a general set function as well with an additional "value" parameter.